# Where is SQLQuery1.sql saved?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Whenever I open up SSMS (SQL Server 2012), I get all of the scripts that I had open in my previous session. This includes both saved queries and any unsaved queries, which are listed as `SQLQuery1.sql`, `SQLQuery2.sql`, etc.

I can't seem to find where these "unsaved" queries are being saved. I've checked `Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files\` (and every other directory in that vicinity). I've also checked the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\` directory and subdirectories (as best I could). Finally, I did a complete search on my computer for the filename `SQLQuery1.sql` and it turned up nothing (not that I trust the Windows search function in file explorer).

In case it changes things at all, I also have installed the Redgate SQL Prompt add-on for SSMS.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: How can you search for unsaved files? Mybe you are looking for `SqlStudio.bin`

Comment: SSMS is obviously saving them for me somewhere, because when I open it back up they are there. I just don't know where it's putting them.

Comment: Surprisingly we don't seem to have a question for this, and now I'm really curious.

Comment: @TomH Can you open them again? (recent files)

Comment: Recent files are recent **saved** files. The question is about 'unsaved'/auto-saved queries, which the user has never explicitly saved or loaded, so they don't appear in Recent.

Comment: @underscore_d If they auto-saved then it must be show the path as a hint when you move the cursor aganist the file tab.

Comment: @Sami No, it doesn't. "Auto-saved" is maybe not the precise term I meant to use, but "unsaved" is accurate.

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple :)

Create new query, then right click on the tab and then choose `Open containing folder` option.

For example, I got `C:\Users\PKuderov\AppData\Local\Temp` folder and my SQLQuery4.sql is named `~vs3C67.sql`.

So @BenjaminSmith is right but these files have unique temporary names. Until you explicitly save them where you want. It seems they survive ssms reload and you can further filter them by `.sql` extension and `Date Modified`.

Comment: We have a winner! This works for me with SSMS 2012: one randomly named file for each tab I have open (plus a bunch of other stuff).

Comment: Thanks. Although I tried "Save As" to find the directory, I didn't know about right-clicking the tab. Unfortunately, all of the .sql files in that directory are empty (either 0 bytes or 1 byte and when I open them there is nothing in there). It seems like this is close though. I need to get some work done, but I'll investigate further afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

How about the TEMP folder? Try searching for %TEMP% from your start menu and searching in there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked there and it was a no-go :(

Answer (score 0):

I got my saved query in the following way.

1. I made another query and selected to save it.
2. It popped out the save as dialogue box from where I got all the things which I required.
3. I copied the file path which was "C:\Users\Shafiq Ur Rehman\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio"

[image]